# How to Solve "devexpress.xtraprinting.drawing.page watermark" in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, vb.net-2010

I am trying to export a GridView (Devexpress gridControl) data to excel or as like format (PDF, HTML, BMP, etc.) thats how I did it?

I am using this sample code

```
GridControl1 .ShowPrintPreview
```

but, this is don't work!!!
why?

this message show- 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To export gridControl data to other format you can use :

```
  gridControl1.ExportToPdf(@"c:\")
  gridControl1.ExportToXlsx(@"c:\")
  gridControl1.ExportToHtml(@"c:\")
```

The **ShowPrintPreview** method can be used for Grid Control's DefaultView

try with :`gridView1.ShowPrintPreview`

[image]

Comment: if your possible plz solve this **ShowPrintPreview** method.

Comment: use gridView1.ShowPrintPreview  not GridControl1 look at the picture in  my answer